# Siegel-Walfisz theorem in proof of Vinogradov's three primes theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Vinogradov's theorem states that for all sufficiently large odd numbers $N$ the equation
$$
N = p_1 + p_2 + p_3
$$
has a solution in prime numbers. I was going through the proof of the theorem in [this paper by Nicholas Rouse](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2013/REUPapers/Rouse.pdf). At one point, while computing the integral over major arcs, I found this:
**Lemma** Let $\chi$ be a nontrivial Dirichlet character to modulus $q$. If $q \leqslant log(x)^M$ for a positive constant M, then
$$
|\psi(x,\chi)| = O\left( x \exp(-C_M \sqrt{\log x}) \right)
$$
for a positive constant $C_M$ which is a function of solely $M$.
[Where
$$
\psi(x,\chi) = \sum_{n \leqslant x} \chi(n) \Lambda(n)
.$$]
This seems like a version of Siegel-Walfisz theorem modified with the Dirichlet character. I was wondering, where could I see the proof of this fact? (I believe it shouldn't be that hard, but I don't want to get too technical)

Comment: Such a deep result requires difficult lemmas , so I would not expect an easy proof. It is amazing that the ternary version of the Goldbach conjecture is now completely solved (thanks to the partial result of Vinogradov which was refined in steps until brute force could be applied) and the binary version still seems to be out of reach (we could as far as I know not even prove it for sufficiently large numbers).

Comment: The standard Siegel-Wallfisz theorem is actually a consequence of this lemma. At least, that's how the theorem is originally proven.